# In what coordinate system the Camera.LookDirection is located?

Tags: wpf, 3d, camera, direction

I have a figure at the origin point (0 0 0). So I setup my perspective camera like

```
<PerspectiveCamera Position="0 0 10" LookDirection="0 0 0" UpDirection="0 1 0" />
```

But there is nothing to see. How it can be? I look straight to the origin point from my position point!

Only one thing can explain this: the LookDirection is located in the Position's coordinate system (CS), i.e. the Position is the origin point of the local CS in which the LookDirection exists. So the Position is in the global CS, and the LookDirection isn't in the global CS. But I don't meet with that explanation in MSDN. Why they don't tell about that?

Am I right or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `LookDirection="0 0 0"` into `LookDirection="0 0 -1"`

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.media3d.projectioncamera.lookdirection.aspx), `LookDirection` is a vector, not a location.

Comment: "Gets or sets a Vector3D which defines the direction in which the camera is looking in WORLD COORDINATES". So If LookDirection is vector, then its origin is the camera Position, and its point of direction is the LookDirection itself. Am I right to this place? If not, where the origin of the LookDirection is located?

Comment: In addition, I understand what LookDirection means in the terms of .NET Framework. But their logic just breaks my mind. It is easier to understand for me the vectors with two points. Otherwise it is not evident where the origin of a vector is located in various cases. So in the camera case I understand that the origin is Position intuitively, but how about other cases?

Answer (score 2):

You're 10 units on the Z axis, and you want to look *at* the origin.

You therefore want to look *backwards* along the Z axis : `LookDirection="0 0 -1"`

Per Benoit's answer, this field is a *vector*, not a *position*.

More generally,

```
LookDirection = ( LookPosition - CameraPosition ).normalize()
```

[NB: that's pseudocode, not real code]

Comment: I read about this formula at C.Petzold's book, but in that case the LookDirection looks like a point of look in the local coordinate system with origin in the LookPosition. Isn't it? And how about the look dorection seems like a point - is it the only arrowed end of a vector?

Comment: @user808128 yes, kind of, to both questions.